# How to get the checked checkbox from a ASP.NET MVC2 form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a hard time in asp.net MVC2 trying to get the checked values of different checkbox.

Here is my view

```
    <div id="RoleSelection">
    <ul>
        <% foreach (var roles in Model.Roles)
           { 
        %>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="roles" value="<%: roles %>" /> <%: roles %>
        </li>
        <%   
            }
        %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My model:

```
    [LocalizedDisplayName("Role", NameResourceType = typeof(UserResources))]
    public string Role { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Roles { get; set; }
```

So basically here I'm trying to figure out how to get all the checked checkbox from my form!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Name` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp) instead of the `id` attribute. The `id` must be unique amongst all element.

The `name` attribute in your case will allow you to regroup the multiple checkbox into a single group.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="roles" value="<%: roles %>" /> <%: roles %>
```